# How to pass ellipsis into data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I was looking to build a function that left joins two datatables on an arbitrary number of columns. However, I am running into an issue when passing an ellipsis into the `on = .()` condition.

Using the data

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

df = data.table(a = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5), 
                b = c(4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13), 
                c = c(1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4), 
                mnd = as.Date(lubridate::ym(c(200701, 200702, 200704, 200705, 200701, 200702, 200701, 200703, 200704, 200705))))

dat = data.table(id = c(1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4), 
                 value = c(rep(30, 2), rep(25, 5), rep(20, 3)), 
                 date = as.Date(lubridate::ym(c(200701, 200702, 200704, 200705, 200701, 200702, 200701, 200703, 200704, 200705))))
```

if I were to do the left join directly

```
df[dat, on = .(mnd = date, c = id), nomatch = NULL]
```

everything works. However, using the function

```
dtable_func = function(input_data, input_data_2, ...) {

    xx = input_data[input_data_2,
                    on = .(...),                # how to join the two tables?
                    nomatch = NULL]

    return(xx)
}
```

I get the error `Error in colnamesInt(x, names(on), check_dups = FALSE) : argument specifying columns specify non existing column(s): cols[1]='...'` which I could not understand. I also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72926127/evaluating-ellipsis-in-data-table-context) but it did not help.

So I was wondering how do we pass in the ellipsis into data.table via a function?

Comment: 'on' arg accept character vector to specify multiple columns to join on including comparison operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make use of NSE:

```
dtable_func <- function(input_data, input_data_2, ...) {    
  by_vals <- as.call(c(quote(.), substitute(...())))
  input_data[input_data_2, on = eval(by_vals), nomatch = NULL]
}

dtable_func(df, dat, mnd = date, c = id)
    a  b c        mnd value
 1: 1  4 1 2007-01-01    30
 2: 1  5 1 2007-02-01    30
 3: 2  6 1 2007-04-01    25
 4: 2  7 2 2007-05-01    25
 5: 3  8 3 2007-01-01    25
 6: 4 10 3 2007-01-01    25
 7: 3  9 3 2007-02-01    25
 8: 3  8 3 2007-01-01    25
 9: 4 10 3 2007-01-01    25
10: 4 11 4 2007-03-01    20
11: 5 12 4 2007-04-01    20
12: 5 13 4 2007-05-01    20
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I appreciate it. It works as hoped. Just one thing, can you explain the code? I'm reading the `by_vals` line as bind the ellipsis components in a vector ('`...()`') and parse the expressions contained within this vector using `substitute`, then use `quote` to get the expression '`.`' and bind this in another vector with the output from `substitute`, then use `as.call()` to create the unevaluated expression '`.(...)`' exactly. This is then evaluated within the data table in `on`. Is that correct?

Comment: @MatthewCassell yes thats correct